# Optimizing Precision Photodiode Sensor Circuit Design-keep-out around the trace calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, pcb-design, noise, shielding

I am going through this document from Analog devices to learn more about different guarding methods.(https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/optimizing-precision-photodiode-sensor-circuit-design.html)

In "**DC Considerations**" paragraph-3 you can see the statement given below.

"*One way to minimize this external leakage path is to increase the resistance between the trace carrying the photodiode current and any other traces. This can be as simple as adding a large routing keep-out around the trace to increase the distance to other traces*"

My question is how to calculate the required keep-out around the trace.

May I know is there any math or thumb rule to calculate the keep-out around the trace.